# Deleting a folder within a folder using two variables

Tags: python

I've got multiple branches in the company folder and then multiple users per branch. I need to remove certain users as they leave a branch. I don't get an error but the entire branch folder gets deleted and not just the specified user folder. Can someone point me in the right direction

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, sys, getopt, shutil
branch, user = "",""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    argv = sys.argv[1:]
    try:
       opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, 'hd:e', ['help', 'branch=', 'user='])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
       print __doc__
       sys.exit()

    for opt, arg in opts:
       if opt in ('-h', '--help'):
           print __doc__
           sys.exit()
       if opt in ('-d', '--branch'):
           branch = arg
       if opt in ('-e', '--user'):
           user = arg

shutil.rmtree("/home/company/%s/%s" % (branch , user))
```

Comment: That sounds like your `user` variable isn't getting set. Consider adding an explicit check or assertion to make sure that `user != ""`.

Comment: As it is here, you have a very funny example of "what not to do", since the rmtree with this indentation will simply erase the whole "/home/company///" tree if this module is imported - for example, if one mistakenly types "import <scriptname> " in an interactive Python console

Comment: do you have any advice on how to do it? my coding skills are minimal so Im doing trial by error here

Answer (score 0):

- It looks like your `rmtree()` call is mis-indented, it should probably only run when in "**main**" mode. As is, it will always run when the module is loaded, with `branch` and `user` both empty. This seems dangerous.
- It seems you should check if you actually got both `branch` and `user` from the options, before calling `rmtree()`.

Comment: I have made the following changes but it would seem that the last %s for user is ignored and that rmtree only recognises the following /home/company/%s. Any ideas? Is there a different way to list the two variables so that only the user folder is deleted?